# How does this transformation from 2d to 3d work mathmatically?

Tags: svm, linear-algebra

[image]

This is the 2d->3d projection for svm. 
They used the kernel trick to change the dimension of the vector for easier classification.

I want to understand the detail math behind this projection

1. which part of math tutorial should I see to understand this projection?
2. why did they use $x_{1}^{2},\sqrt{2}x_{1}x_{2}, x_{2}^{2}$ for transaction?

Comment: Do you have a reference to who is 'they'?

Answer (score 1):

This is [polynomial kernel](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Polynomial_kernel) with degree $d=2$ and $c=0$, which is commonly used for higher dimension transformations for SVM. Another similar one is RBF kernel. Since SVM is a linear model, such transformations are used to separate nonlinearly separable data, as in your example.

Normally, the data points $x,y$ have dot product $K(x,y)=x^Ty$. This is called as linear kernel, and there is no transformation. If we want to see these dot products in another form, e.g. as in polynomial kernel here $K(x,y)=(x^Ty+c)^d$, we apply some transformation to the data, i.e. $x\rightarrow \phi(x)$ such that you create the desired kernel, i.e. $K(x,y)=(x^Ty+c)^d=\phi(x)^T\phi(y)$. The question here is to find this transformation.

In this problem, $\phi(x)$ is $[x_1^2 \ \sqrt{2}x_1x_2\ x_2^2]^T$. If we want to verify it:
$$\phi(x)^T\phi(y)=x_1^2y_1^2+x_2^2y_2^2+2x_1x_2y_1y_2=(x_1y_1+x_2y_2)^2=(x^Ty)^2$$

where $x=[x_1 \ x_2]^T, y = [y_1\ y_2]^T$.