# Mathematical steps for solving the Kernel trick for Support Vector Machines (SVM)s

Tags: machine-learning, svm, kernel-trick, rbf-kernel

I am trying to understand the math behind the Support Vector Machines (SVM) Kernel Trick but there isn't any real source online for the mathematical steps to I can follow to see how its solved. One example is [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/401304/how-does-this-transformation-from-2d-to-3d-work-mathmatically), but the answer didn't show how it was actually calculated using the numbers for the data points.

Could someone use a simple example with numbers or that example I linked above to show the math for solving it?